# Why does `filter` crash with an input length error in my shiny app?

Tags: r, input, dplyr, gsub

i am pretty new to programmring but i have to make a shiny app for a university course.

As you can see i webscraped a data table thats presents different bike geometries and i wanted to create a shiny app, where i can compare the geometries with each other. I am quite happy with my progress, but now i got the problem that it always shows me the error: "Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 19 or 1, not size 0.
i Input `..1` is `!=...`.  161: "

I want that its possible in the app to choose one bike and it automatically compares the bike and shows me the 10 most similar bikes.

```
#table

Canyon <- read_html("https://enduro-mtb.com/canyon-strive-cfr-9-0-ltd-test-2020/")
Rose <- read_html("https://enduro-mtb.com/rose-root-miller-2020-test/")
Ghost <- read_html("https://enduro-mtb.com/ghost-riot-enduro-2021-erster-test/")
Cube <- read_html("https://enduro-mtb.com/cube-stereo-170-sl-29-test-2020/")


Comparison <- tibble(
  Geometry = Canyon %>%
    html_nodes(".geometry strong") %>%
    html_text()%>%
    str_trim(),
  CanyonStrive = Canyon %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()%>%
    str_trim(),
  GhostRiot = Ghost %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()%>%
    str_trim(),
   CubeStereo = Cube %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()%>%
    str_trim(),
   RoseRootMiller = Rose %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>%
    html_text()%>%
    str_trim(),
)

ComparisonTable <- Comparison %>%
  mutate_all(~gsub("mm|°|-.*|/.*|\\.", "", .)) %>%
  mutate_all(~gsub(",", ".", .)) %>%
  mutate_all(type.convert, as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  gather("Bikes", "value", 2:ncol(Comparison)) %>% 
  spread(Geometry,value)


Art <- c("Enduro", "Enduro", "AllMountain", "Enduro")


ComparisonTableHallo <- ComparisonTable

ComparisonTableHallo$Art <- Art

# server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 selectedData1 <- reactive({
      ComparisonTableHallo %>%
      filter(ComparisonTableHallo$Bikes != gsub("[[:space:]]*$","",gsub("- .*",'',input$Bikes))) 
    })
    
     
    
    selectedData2 <- reactive({
      selectedData1() %>%
        select(1:12) %>%
      filter(selectedData1()$Art %in% input$Art) 
    })
    
    selectedData3 <- reactive({
      ComparisonTableHallo  %>%
        select(1:12) %>%
        filter(ComparisonTableHallo$Bikes == gsub("[[:space:]]*$","",gsub("- .*",'',input$Bikes))) 
      
    })
    
    selectedData4 <- reactive({
      rbind(selectedData3(),selectedData2())
      
    })
    
    selectedData5 <- reactive({
      selectedData4() %>%
      select(3:11)
    })
    
    selectedData6 <- reactive({
    as.numeric(knnx.index(selectedData5(), selectedData5()[1, , drop=FALSE], k=2))
    })
    
    selectedData7 <- reactive({
      selectedData4()[selectedData6(),]
    })
    
    selectedData8 <- reactive({
      selectedData7() %>%
        select(3:11)
    })


    # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    
    validate(
      need(dim(selectedData2())[1]>=2, "Sorry, no ten similar bikes were found. 
           Please change the input filters."
      )
      )

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      mode = "closest",
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[1,]),
        theta = c("Kettenstrebe", "Lenkwinkel","Oberrohr","Radstand","Reach","Sattelrohr","Sitzwinkel","Stack","Steuerrohr",
                  "Tretlagerabsenkung"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        name = selectedData7()[1,1]
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.matrix(selectedData8()[2,]),
        theta = c("Kettenstrebe","Lenkwinkel","Oberrohr","Radstand","Reach","Sattelrohr","Sitzwinkel","Stack","Steuerrohr",
                  "Tretlagerabsenkung"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        visible="legendonly",
        name = selectedData7()[2,1]
      ) %>% 
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,100)
          )
       ),
     
     showlegend=TRUE
      
        
      )
    
  })
  
}

#shiny app

ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage("Bike Comparison",
           tabPanel("Graphic",fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly")),
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML(".shiny-output-error-validation{color: red;}"))),
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Apply filters'),
  sidebarPanel(width = 4,
    selectInput('Bike', 'Choose a Bike:',paste(ComparisonTableHallo$Bikes)),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Art",
                       label = 'Art:', choices = c("Enduro" = "Enduro", "AllMountain" = "AllMountain"
                                                        ), 
                       selected = c("Enduro" = "Enduro","AllMountain" = "AllMountain"),inline=TRUE),
   submitButton("Update filters")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    column(8, plotlyOutput("plot1", width = 800, height=700),
           p("To visualize the graph of the player, click the icon at side of names 
             in the graphic legend. It is worth noting that graphics will be overlapped.",
             style = "font-size:25px")
    
  )
  )
)))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Andrea. Welcome to stack overflow. There are a few issues with this question:

Comment: It contains a lot of uninformative text, such as "It would be great if someone could help" and "I already tried everything I found on the internet". Please avoid pleasantries and details which are unrelated to the question

Comment: It's also mostly code - I attempted to remove the surplus information, but S.O reject the edit because the ratio of code to non-code was so high! Please try to make your example as minimal as possible. Please remove the 'install.packages' loop, as I'm not sure many of those packages are used in the code. If the code requires a package, just use `require("package")` - users can install if they wish.

Comment: Ok I try to change everything! Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0):

On your UI, your input is named `Bike`, on your server, you are referring to  `input$Bikes`. Either Bike needs to change to Bikes, or the opposite.

Edit: (elaboration) Your error is telling you that you have a problem with one your arguments to the function `filter`. Specifically, you're passing an object of length 0 to the function. You are trying to pass the Bike.  An empty select input would pass `""`, so that isn't the problem. `""` has length 1. However an input you never assigned would pass `NULL`. That has length 0.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, helped at least it opens the shiny app now and i get a result but it is wrong. Sadly.

Comment: Unfortunately, for more help you'll probably need to post a new question describing your new issue.  Your posted problem was the filter crash. That sounds solved.